# MySQL AND operator?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a problem with a sql query.
I have a table like this:

```
user_id  exception
  2        3
  2        4
```

I want to select the `user_id's` which exists with the exception `3 AND 4`

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM table 
WHERE exception = 3 
  AND exception = 4
```

doesn't work.

Comment: The English language is a problem.  "And" sometimes means "Or".  In Math and Computers, there is a precise difference.  You need `OR` in this situation.  But, since there is no "Both" operator.  Hence the `HAVING COUNT...` solutions below.

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregation and `having`:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM table 
WHERE exception in (3, 4)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT exception) = 2;
```

This returns users who have both exceptions.  If there are no duplicates for users/exceptions, then use `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Your current query selects the `user_id` where the exception is both 3 and 4 - which can never be true, as a single cell only holds one value.

In order to select the `user_id` which have both the row of 3 and 4, you'll need to run a query where the exception is 3 or 4, and `GROUP BY` the `user_id`. Then you can use the aggregate function `COUNT()`, to find where there are two rows - which will be the rows where the exception is 3 and 4.

This assumes that there is a unique relation between the `user_id` and `exception`, meaning that the combination of `user_id` and `exception` never appear twice.

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM table 
WHERE exception IN (3, 4)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 2
```

- [MySQL `GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)
- [MySQL `COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html)

Comment: thanks for you answer... I want to select just the user id's wich have both exceptions not one of the two

Comment: Seems like I misunderstood your question. If that's the case, you'd need to `GROUP BY` and see where the `COUNT()` is two. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

use exists

```
  select t1.* from table_name t1
  where exists ( select 1 from table_name t2 where t1.user_id=t2.user_id
                                            where exception in (3,4)
                                            having count(distinct exception)=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The below query will give you the users who have faced both exceptions 3 & 4, if that is what you are looking for

```
select user_id from table where exception=3 
intersect 
select user_id from table where exception=4
```

Or try

Select user_id from table a were exception=3 and exists ( select user_id from table b where exception=4 and a.user_id=b.user_id)

Comment: This is a very good approach. Unfortunately, however, MySQL doesn't feature `INTERSECT`.

Answer (score 1):

I will provide you one suggestion

Create two columns(fields) in the database table called **exception_1** and **exception_2** . Now your table looks like the below,

```
user_id  exception_1  exception_2
  2        3            4
  2        4            3
  3        3            4
```

and then execute the below query.

```
SELECT user_id FROM table WHERE exception_1 = 3 AND exception_2 = 4
```

Comment: No. Qirel's answer is wrong, because they misread the requirement. maximus26 wants userids that have exception 3 **AND** 4, i.e. both. And your suggestion is to add a column to the table in order to redundantly store values redundantly? That is a horrible idea.

Comment: No, there is no chance of getting the user_id's data using AND operator from one column. He(maximus26) is writing the query where the exception is both 3 and 4, which can never be true - as the value of a single cell can't be 3 AND 4 at the same time. Otherwise, he needs to create the two columns as my answer.

Comment: No. Look at Gordon's answer. This is how to get the IDs that have both exception 3 and 4. Qirel has updated their answer to match Gordon's. forpas has added an answer that does the same, only slightly different. zulfi123786 shows another good approach that only doesn't work in MySQL. rad has added yet another solution. All those solutions work. There is no need to change the data model. Your suggestion is just very, very bad. It is correct that you cannot use the AND operator like maximus26 tried, but you can still get the userids that have both exception 3 AND 4.

Answer (score 0):

With `group by` and `min` and `max`:

```
select user_id 
from tablename 
where exception in (3, 4)
group by user_id
having min(exception) = 3 and max(exception) = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `self join`:

```
select u1.user_id from 
tbl_user u1 join tbl_user u2
on u1.user_id = u2.user_id
where u1.exception = 3 and u2.exception = 4
```